# How does Gedit expose its api to python for plugins?

Tags: c++, python, plugins, gedit

I'm starting a medium (academic) project in C++ for which I need users to be able to write small scripts, which interact directly with the main program. My first thought as an aproach to this was to make something like Gedit does with it's plugins (in fact I thought about it because it is something very similar to what I need to do.)

I *do* have some experience writting plugins for geddit, but zero experience in writting a plugin framework.
Would it be really difficult to me to write one similar to gedit's? (i mean, the way it exposes its API to python, and then loads the python plugin and calls its methods). Can anyone point me in the right directions or teach me a little if you have experience with it?

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, gedit's plugin framework can be used. You could use Ethos, which is the same plugin framework gedit uses, only without gedit.

Comment: Never heard of it before, but it looks really cool, the only con is that it is not C++ (i need it to be C++).